# Como pegar coordenadas pelo click do mouse com Python?

Tags: python-3.x, eventos-do-mouse

Eu tenho um código que me retorna o valor de uma cor em hexadecimal em uma determinada coordenada, no caso do código as coordenadas são 200 e 200, o problema é que ficar colocando esses valores pelo teclado  é meio trabalhoso, teria alguma forma de adicionar essas coordenadas através de um clique de mouse ?. tipo ao clicar no ponto onde quero as coordenadas vão diretamente para ali, para o getpixel()? Muito obrigado

```
import pyautogui

pixelColor = pyautogui.screenshot().getpixel((200,200,)) pixelColor = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (pixelColor) print(pixelColor)
```

Answer (score -1):

Bom uma forma de fazer isso em pyautogui seria basicamente assim:

```
#pega o retorno da posicao atual de x e y do mouse e passa o valor da tupla para as duas variaveis
x, y = pyautogui.position()
print ("Posicao atual do mouse:")
print ("x = "+str(x)+" y = "+str(y))

#retorna True se x & y estiverem dentro da tela
print ("\nEsta dentro da tela?")
resp = pyautogui.onScreen(x, y)
print (str(resp))
```

Comment: Obrigado campeão mas acho que me expressei mal, eu não queria as coordenadas do mouse, queria pegar as coordenadas com o click do mouse ao invés de eu ficar colocando os valores através do teclado. Eu clico na minha tela e ele captura as coordenadas e as joga no meu código.